# Why is a document for which _explain returns matched: true not being returned by _search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm scratching my head over the following Elasticsearch problem:

GET `/myindex/mytype/_search` with the following body:

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": "attorneys"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "attorneys",
            "type": "most_fields",
            "fields": [
              "name^2",
              "description"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "boost": 2.0,
            "path": "categories",
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "categories.name": {
                        "fuzziness": 10,
                        "query": "attorneys"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "categories.name": "attorneys"
                    }
                  }
                ]
// ...closing brackets trimmed for conciseness
```

doesn't return the document with with ID=10007.

However, GET `/myindex/mytype/10007/_explain` with exactly the same query body returns:

```js
{
  "_index": "vendors",
  "_type": "vendor",
  "_id": "10007",
  "matched": true,
  "explanation": {
    "value": 0.26991397,
    "description": "product of:",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 0.8097419,
        "description": "sum of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 0.8097419,
            "description": "Score based on child doc range from 304 to 304"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": 0.33333334,
        "description": "coord(1/3)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why would `_explain` return `"matched": true` but `_query` not return the
document?

Comment: How many total results does your query match? Since you don't specify `from/size`, the default is to return the first 10 results. Maybe the document 10007 comes later than that.

Comment: That was my first thought - it matches 11 results currently, though, and increasing "size" doesn't change anything

Comment: Actually scratch that - the "hits" in the result body was 11 but only the first 10 of those 11 were present. @Val post that as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many total results does your query match? Since you don't specify from/size, the default is to return the first 10 results. Maybe the document 10007 comes later than that.